# pairplot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'linewidth'

Tags: python, seaborn

Im trying to turn off the white border around the dots in a `pairplot`,
I've tried assigning `linewidth=0`
And got the error `pairplot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'linewidth'`

Referring the docs i found that it dosen't
states anything about linewidth
with `pairplot()`

So how can i use the `linewidth=0` function with a pairplot..?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

DATA= pd.read_csv("/storage/emulated/0/Download/iris-write-from-docker.csv")
 
sns.pairplot(data=DATA)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Did you try `plot_kws={'linewidth':0}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

> I actually want to turn off the white border around the dots/bars inside the scatterplot/histogram diagram in the pairplot

Use the `diag_kws` and `plot_kws` parameters:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

penguins = sns.load_dataset("penguins")
sns.pairplot(penguins, diag_kws={'linewidth': 0}, plot_kws={'linewidth': 0})
plt.show()
```

[image: pairplot]